# Understanding ssl certificates

Tags: ssl, https

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how many ssl certificates I should get under specific conditions:

- I have two pages the user is supposed to ***use*** (index and main) and all other scripts users don't access in the front end (e.g. uploadFile.php).
- I have socket.io implemented in port **x** which I want to run over https protocol.

How many ssl certificates should I get under these conditions to assure secure data traffic? (is the data from all other php scripts still secure if index and main have ssl?)

Answer (score 0):

SSL cert is issued for a specific DNS name. So if you run your PHP and Socket.io applications on the same domain, one cert is surely enough to secure both.

If you run your app on two different domains, you need to (a) use two separate regular certificates, or (b) have one SAN certificate (it secures multiple DNS names).

Also there is a wildcard certificate, it secures all direct subdomains of specified domain (*.some-site.com). It can be combined with SAN feature, so it can secure base domain some-site.com and direct subdomains as well.

Comment: considering someone accesses my service **some-site.com** via **something**.some-site.com and I have ssl certificate for some-site.com, is https implemented anyway?

Answer (score 0):

IF your website is accessed via different website on https , then your website and the website through which its accessed needs to have their separate SSL certificate.

If your website does not have an ssl certificate , the connection will be dropped when your website link is accessed via other website.